# How do I calculate a 2D Vector from a dot product or a signed angle?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, vector, dot-product

I have the following scenario:

I am working on a top-down 2-dimensional (XZ plane) game and i need to calculate the difference
of the characters movement direction (moveDir) to the look direction (lookDir).

I would like to calculate a 2D Vector (xy) that holds the following information:

The X value should range from -1 (character facing backwards) to 1 (facing forwards)

The Y value should also range from -1 (character facing left) to 1 (facing right).

To calculate the X value I can use the dot product of moveDir and lookDir.
However, I dont understand how to correctly calculate the Y value. I assume that I have to use the signedAngle between moveDir and lookDir, as the signedAngle returns a value of -90 if the character is facing left and 90 if its facing right.

I could probably even use the signedAngle between the vectors for calculating both X and Y values, as a signedAngle of 0 has the same meaning as a dot product of 1 (and also the same applies to a signedAngle of 180 and the dot product of -1).

How do I calculate the missing part?

Comment: you mean like using [`Vector2.Dot`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.Dot.html) ?

Comment: now that i think about it:

1 - Vector2.Dot(...) equals 1 if the character is turned by 90 degrees to left or right.
If i multiply this with -1 if the signed angle is  < 180 i get a value that goes from -1 to 1

Comment: I can understand you calculate moveDir by difference of two positions but how do you calculate lookDir. I mean, where does it come from? I need to understand how this model works.

Comment: First remark, the dot product of 2 vectors is not between -1 and 1, so you should divide the dot product by the product of the 2 norms of the vectors. This is the same as taking the cosine of the angle between the vectors. The cosine is always between -1 and 1.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, i have linked a solution that works very well in my scenario.
It returns values from -1 to 1, depending if the character is facing left or right (and 0 if facing forwards or backwards)

Comment: If I understand your model, the sine of your signed Angle will be Y.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the following solution (pseudocode):

```
y = 1 - absoluteValue(dotProduct(lookDir, moveDir))

if (signedAngle(lookDir, moveDir) <= 0
    y *= -1
```

Comment: Are lookDir and moveDir normalized vectors? (and check my previous latest comment please)

Comment: Please also note that if you take the sine or cosine of an angle, you have to convert the angle from degrees to radians first : X = Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad(signedAngle)) and Y = Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad(signedAngle))

Comment: Your solution is very approximative, please see this: your solution is in red, mine in blue. https://www.desmos.com/calculator/llbtshkkkf

Comment: Hey, i dont quite understand your solution!
Can you explain why my solution is the red graph? Also, why is sin(x) the solution you propose? Oh and, my vectors are just two normalized 2-dimensional vectors, if that helps :)

Comment: Yes it is important that the vectors have a norm = 1 because otherwise your dotproduct could be higher. In fact you dotproduct is equal to the cosine and that is what you want. I just translated your formula into the grapher. The formula x/|x| returns 1 if x>0 and -1 if x<0, so it matches your test if the signed angle is negative... Now my formula is good because when you have a rotating spinning normalized vector, its projections are naturaly (cos alpha, sin alpha) where alpha is the angle between the x-axis and the vector. Positive angles are clockwise.  (to be continued)

Comment: (continuation) You take your signed angle between lookDir and moveDir because you want the positive way to be counter clockwise, and it's a wise decision!

Answer (score 0):

As said assuming both `moveDir` and `lookDir` are normalized vectors I think you can simply use [`Vector2.Dot`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.Dot.html) for the first one:

```
var x = Vector2.Dot(moveDir, lookDir);
```

this will return a value between `1` (`lookDir == moveDir` => looking "forward") and `-1` (`lookDir == -moveDir` => looking "back") and `0` would mean it is perpendicular.

Then for "left" and "right" you can **cheat** a little bit and basically do the same but using [`Vector3.Cross`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Cross.html) (note that even though you only want 2D vectors Unity is a 3D engine after all) in order to first obtain a vector that supposedly **is** "right" like e.g.

```
var y = Vector2.Dot(lookDir, Vector3.Cross(moveDir, Vector3.forward).normalized);
```

to explain this a bit

- we use `Vector3.forward` which is basically `(0, 0, 1)` (a vector pointing into the screen away from you) since you are dealing with `Vector2` vectors which move on the `XY` plane. So in order to get a perpendicular vector to a `Vector2` we first need a vector that is perpendicular to all of them on the third axis
- `Vector3.Cross` uses left hand rule

  [image]

  so

  ```
   Vector3.Cross(moveDir, Vector3.forward)
  ```

  returns a Vector pointing 90° to the "right" from the `moveDir`
- `Vector3` and `Vector2` are implicitly convertible into each other which will simply ignore the `Z` component or use `0`

**OR** as Fredy pointed out you can also simply use

```
var y = Mathf.Sin(Vector2.SignedAngle(lookDir, moveDir) * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
```

which basically does the same and is probably less complicated ;)

[image]

Comment: The norm of a crossproduct is the sine of the angle (with normalized vectors). Why do simple when you can complicate!!!

Comment: @Fredy I see your point about the sinus though ;)

Comment: :D great GIF ;)